# Increase value of an object inside a function everytime it gets called

Tags: r, function

I have a function say,

```
inc <- function(t) {
       f <- 1
       t + f
}
```

So, for the first time function `inc` gets called, `f` will be `1`, but the next time it gets called `f` value should be `2` and when the function `inc` gets called for the 3rd time `f` value should be `3` and so on...

How do I do it in R?

Comment: What are you trying to do with it eventually?

Comment: You can use this for memoization, but for almost all other purposes you shouldn't do this. It violates the functional language paradigm.

Comment: Check out Hadley Wickham's book, here's the exact example: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functional-programming.html#mutable-state

Answer (score 7):

I usually use this. I don't know if it is a trick or an hack:

```
getF <- function(){
   x <- 1
   function(t){
      x <<- t + x
   }
}

f <- getF()
```

`f` is a function (the return value of `getF`) and it's enclosing environment is not the global environment, but the environment wherein `f` was defined. Look at `environment(f)`. `<<-` assigns `x` into that environment: see `ls(environment(f))` and `get("x", environment(f))`.

```
print(f(3))#4
print(f(4))#8
```

Comment: I don't get it. Can somebody explain?

Comment: @user3664020 `getF` returns a function (look at `print(f)`). `<<-` increases `x` in `getF`'s environment, which encloses `f`'s environment.

Comment: @user3664020 f is a function because getF returns a function. 
When you call f(t) you execute x <- t + x where x is a variable associated to f.

Comment: @Roland It has a counter-intuitive behavior when it is copied: x behaves as a shared variable! I hope an R's guru explains it to me.
Try the following lines: g <- f; print(g(2)); print(f(2)); h <- getF(); print(h(1)); print(f(1)); print(g(1));

Comment: @jimifiki Each call to `getF` returns a function with an associated environment (see `environment(f)`). `<<-` assigns to that environment (see `ls(environment(f))`). `g` is just a copy of `f` (with the same environment) whereas `h` is a new function (with a new environment).

Comment: It's definitely not a trick or a hack. Try, for example, `demo("scoping")` (where this is referred to -- as it frequently is -- as an example of a closure) to see that it's documented in base R.

Comment: great for sequential figure and table titles in an RMD report!

Answer (score 3):

This might be easier to understand, but creates an environment in the workspace as a side effect:

```
inc <- function(t) {
  if (!exists("e")) {
    e <<- new.env()
    e$x <- 1
  }

  e$x <- e$x + t
  e$x
}

inc(2)
#[1] 3
inc(2)
#[1] 5
```